# Cloud-based visual tool to perform NLP on text corpora

Tags: nlp, tools, corpus

I have some text corpora to share with non-programming clients (~50K documents, ~100M tokens) who would like to perform operations like regex searches, co-locations, Named-entity recognition, and word clusters. The tool [AntConc](https://www.laurenceanthony.net/software/antconc/) is nice and can do some of these things, but comes with severe size limitations, and crashes on these corpora even on powerful machines.

What cloud-based tools with a web interface would you recommend for this kind of task? Is there an open-source tool or a cloud service at a reasonable cost (<$1,000 for the volume of data indicated above)?